# PHP array formatted by html and group it

Tags: php, html, arrays

I want to format the output of PHP array into HTML, that will align properly. And how will remove the array and other stuffs?
Also, I want to group it by "ou". Ou have 4 or more categories.

The output will be like this with html table

```
 sn      dn                                        mail
 user    cn=user,ou=web service,dc=domain,dc=com   example@domain.com
```

Or like this

```
 sn      dn                                        mail                 ou
 user    cn=user,ou=web service,dc=domain,dc=com   example@domain.com   web service
```

Please help me. Thank you

Here's the output without html

```
 array(1410) { ["count"]=> int(1409) [0]=> array(4) { ["sn"]=> array(2) {   ["count"]=> int(1) [0]=> string(11) "user" } [0]=> string(2) "sn" ["count"]=> int(1) ["dn"]=> string(56) "cn=user,ou=web service,dc=domain,dc=com" } [1]=>.....
```

Here's the PHP array

```
  $dn = 'dc=domain,dc=com';
  $filter = "(|(sn=$person*)(fullname=$person*))";
  $ldaparray = array ("ou", "sn", "fullname", "mail");
  $sr=ldap_search($ldapconn, $dn, $filter, $ldaparray);
  $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $sr);
  var_dump($info);
```

Output using print_r

```
Array
(
[count] => 1409
[0] => Array
    (
        [sn] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
                [0] => user
            )

        [0] => sn
        [count] => 1
        [dn] => cn=username,ou=webservice,dc=domain,dc=com
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [sn] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
                [0] => user
            )

        [0] => sn
        [mail] => Array
            (
                [count] => 1
                [0] => example@domain.com
            )

        [1] => mail
        [count] => 2
        [dn] => uid=userid,ou=webser,dc=doamin,dc=com
    )
```

Comment: duplicate question, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125276/php-foreach-array-to-table-display

Comment: I can't understand how to format my array like in that post

Comment: @Glavić pls help me with, I saw your post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125276/php-foreach-array-to-table-display and I can't figure it out how it will works with my array

Comment: post your sample array.

Comment: @vartateInfo i already posted it

Comment: you posted var_dump result. i said array sample. use <?php print_r($array); ?> to get format.

Answer (score 0):

OMG, var_dump is not a function to write down a content of an array!!!

If you want to write down a content of array, you must use loop. The loop for arrays is called "foreach". So at the place, you want to view a content of array, try

```
<?
 foreach($info as $val) {
echo $val["count"]; // this write down a value of each "count" in array
/* All another array values are now available in variable $val with index you gave them*/
}
?>
```

Comment: didnt work, when I use your script, the out is integer like this 11112222222222122222222222222222222222222222211222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222

Comment: Of course, that is values of $info, but only ["count"] indexes... you must to define in loop another indexes, to get, what you want... these numbers are values of $info["count"]. Try for exapmle echo $val["dn"]

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting just one result to be returned? If so, your result will be in $info[0]. So to display in a table, you could do this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td>Key</td><td>Value</td><tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php foreach($info[0] as $key => $value): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

That said, if your array has other nested arrays, you'll need to adjust your logic accordingly, or you may want to loop through and re-build the array based on the values you're interested in.

Comment: I have thousand of results to be returned

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($info); //your array
    echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This works with nice indentations.

Comment: but i just need only the value to be displayed. Btw, thanks with this, my array looks better now